# Differences between Extractors and Privacy Amplification for Quantum Random Generators

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms

We know that for the last step of QRNG: we need to separate quantum and classical noises from each other so we use extractors, after extractor we need privacy amplification step. At this point:
if extractor is a strong extractor we can use it as a privacy amplification too. However I could not understand differences between extractor and privacy amplification. If I use the strong extractor for the second time, will I be able to complete my privacy amplification step?
What will change in privacy amplification?
If what happens, privacy amplification will be completed?
Thanks